# NEED TO STORE THE mail id USER INPUT IN A FORM TO THE DATABASE

Tags: php, html

I have created a html form in php. i need to get the user input from the form and need to submit in the database.for mail id it show as mail id not the mail id which i have entered.need to show what mail id i have entered .

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>child info</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'admin';
$dbpass = 'admin@123';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $ChildName = addslashes ($_POST['ChildName']);
   $DOB = addslashes ($_POST['DOB']);
   $Gender = addslashes ($_POST['Gender']);
   $Grade = addslashes ($_POST['Grade']);
   $BloodGroup = addslashes ($_POST['BloodGroup']);
   $FatherName = addslashes ($_POST['FatherName']);
   $MotherName = addslashes ($_POST['MotherName']);
   $GuardianName = addslashes ($_POST['GuardianName']);
   $LandlineNumber = addslashes ($_POST['LandlineNumber']);
   $MobileNumber = addslashes ($_POST['MobileNumber']);
   $Email_Id = addslashes ($_POST['Email_Id']);
   $Child_Photo = addslashes ($_POST['Child_Photo']);
   $Address = addslashes ($_POST['Address']);
}
else
{
   $ChildName = $_POST['ChildName'];
   $DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
   $Gender =$_POST['Gender'];
   $Grade = $_POST['Grade'];
   $BloodGroup = $_POST['BloodGroup'];
   $FatherName = $_POST['FatherName'];
   $MotherName = $_POST['MotherName'];
   $GuardianName = $_POST['GuardianName'];
   $LandlineNumber =$_POST[' LandlineNumber'];
   $MobileNumber = $_POST['MobileNumber'];
   $Email_Id = $_POST['Email_Id'];
   $Child_Photo = $_POST['Child_Photo'];
   $Address = $_POST['Address'];
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO child_info(ChildName,DOB,Gender,Grade,BloodGroup,FatherName,MotherName,GuardianName,LandlineNumber,MobileNumber,Email_Id,Child_Photo,Address) VALUES ('$ChildName','$DOB','$Gender','$Grade','$BloodGroup','$FatherName','$MotherName','$GuardianName','$LandlineNumber','$MobileNumber','Email_Id','$Child_Photo','$Address')";
mysql_select_db('admin_data');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
    <title>child_info</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/child_info.css">
    <script src="js/notification.js">   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
            <div class="layout">

            <div class="img1"></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" >
                <label class="ChildName">CHILD NAME</label><input type="text" placeholder="ChildName" id="ChildName" name="ChildName">
                <label class="DOB">DATE OF BIRTH</label><input type="date" placeholder="D.O.B" id="DOB" name="DOB">
                <label class="Gender">GENDER</label>
                <label class="Male">Male</label><input  type="radio" name="Gender" value="male" id="Gender" >
                <label class="Female">Female</label><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female" id="Gender">
                <label class="Grade1">GRADE</label>
                <select class=" Grade" id="Grade" name="Grade">
                     <option>KG1</option><option>KG2</option><option>A</option><option>B</option>
                    <option>C</option><option>D</option><option>E</option>
                    <option>F</option><option>G</option><option>H</option><option>I</option><option>J</option><option>K</option>
                </select>
                <label class="BloodGroup">BLOOD GROUP</label><input type="text" placeholder="BLOOD GROUP" id="BloodGroup" name="BloodGroup">
                <label class="FatherName">FATHER NAME</label><input type="text" placeholder="FATHER NAME" id="FatherName" name="FatherName">
                <label class="MotherName">MOTHER NAME</label><input type="text" placeholder="MOTHER NAME" id="MotherName" name="MotherName">
                <label class="GuardianName">GUARDIAN NAME</label><input type="text" placeholder="GUARDIAN NAME" id="GuardianName" name="GuardianName">
                <label class="LandlineNumber">LANDLINE</label><input type="tel" placeholder="LANDLINE" id="LandlineNumber" name="LandlineNumber">
                <label class="MobileNumber">MOBILE NUMBER</label><input type="tel" placeholder="MOBILE NUMBER" id="MobileNumber" name="MobileNumber">
                <label class="Email_Id">MAIL ID</label><input type="email" placeholder="MAIL ID" id="Email_Id" name="Email_Id">
                <label class="child_image">CHILD PHOTO</label><input type="file"  id="Child_Photo" name="Child_Photo">

                <label class="Address">Address</label><textarea  id="Address" name="Address" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="save" id="save" name="save">
                <!--<input type="reset" button onclick='window.location="menu.php"' name="Send Notification" id="save" value="Save">
                <input type="reset" button onclick="javascript:eraseText() name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">-->
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what's the specific error or problem that arises? What have you tried to debug it? Also read up on proper database escaping (which does *not* involve `addslashes`.)

Comment: in database it not showing the the mail id which i have entered .in default it show as MAIL id.

Comment: Your new question could have been avoided as by-product of using prepared statements. It's less easy to find the missing variable prefix in your concatenated string now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the INSERT query you missed out a "$" sign for the Email ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in your query, you are missing a `$` in front of `Email_Id` in this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO child_info(ChildName,DOB,Gender,Grade,BloodGroup,FatherName,MotherName,GuardianName,LandlineNumber,MobileNumber,Email_Id,Child_Photo,Address) VALUES ('$ChildName','$DOB','$Gender','$Grade','$BloodGroup','$FatherName','$MotherName','$GuardianName','$LandlineNumber','$MobileNumber','Email_Id','$Child_Photo','$Address')";
```

It should work if you change the line to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO child_info(ChildName,DOB,Gender,Grade,BloodGroup,FatherName,MotherName,GuardianName,LandlineNumber,MobileNumber,Email_Id,Child_Photo,Address) VALUES ('$ChildName','$DOB','$Gender','$Grade','$BloodGroup','$FatherName','$MotherName','$GuardianName','$LandlineNumber','$MobileNumber','$Email_Id','$Child_Photo','$Address')";
```

But, as mario stated, you should really look into proper db escaping such as PDO.